# .htaccess regex don't works

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pcre

This is my `.htaccess` file,
i want that
`www.example.com/en/home`
redirect to
`www.example.com/pages/en/home`
I've already tried with an online pcre regex tester [regex101](https://regex101.com/), but there it works... thank to all guys!

```
##Debug on normal apache servers
#php_flag display_errors on
#php_value error_reporting E_ALL
##Errors pages
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
RewriteEngine On
##Force SSL
#Normal way
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#Heroku way
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
##.php extension is optional
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule (^.+)$(\/[a-z]{2}\/.+)$ $1/pages$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: You have 2 ending anchors, in this regex, `(^.+)$(\/[a-z]{2}\/.+)$`.

Comment: my fault... but that's still doesn't works.

Comment: Maybe `/([a-z]{2})/(.+)$` then `$1/pages/$2`. You want `/pages/en/home` or `en/pages/home`? Your rule and description seem to differ there. `mod_rewrite` doesnt use delimiters so the `/`s dont need to be escaped.

Comment: Even    (^.+)/([a-z]{2})/(.+)$ $1/pages/$2 doesn't works... i want that the user sees /en/home but the real path is /pages/en/home

Comment: Did you try the regex I provided (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876288/htaccess-regex-dont-works?noredirect=1#comment76731363_44876288)? `(^.+)/([a-z]{2})/(.+)$` != `/([a-z]{2})/(.+)$`. You have 3 capture groups there and are requiring something before the first `/`. The rewrite order would be `/pages/$1/$2` though... or you could just join the `en/home` into 1 capture group.

Comment: ok now i've tried even that :(

Comment: ...and it didn't work, went to the wrong location, other? Do you have a base defined?